# implementing own compareTo and compare Methods

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

im working on some old tasks given by my Programming course.
Im supposed to create a Rectangle class with some basic functions and a lot of Comparable and Comparator classes.

This is what I've got already:

```
public class Rectangle {
    private int length, width;
    public Rectangle(int length, int width) {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }
    public int length() {
        return length;
    }
    public int width() {
        return width;
    }
    public int area() {
        return length + width;
    }
    public int perimeter() {
        return 2 * length + 2 * width;
    }
}

public class RectangleComparable extends Rectangle implements Comparable<RectangleComparable> {
    public RectangleComparable(int length, int width) {
        super(length, width);
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(RectangleComparable r) {
        if (this.area() < o.area()) return -1;
        else if (this.area > o.area()) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }
}

public class RectangleComparatorArea implements Comparable<RectangleComparable> {
    private int area;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(RectangleComparable r) {
        if (area < r.area()) return -1;
        else if (area > r.area()) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }
}

public class RectangleComparatorPerimeter implements Comparable<RectangleComparable> {
    private int perimeter;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(RectangleComparable r) {
        if (perimeter < r.perimeter()) return -1;
        else if (perimeter > r.perimeter()) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }
}

public class ComparableComparator<T> implements java.util.Comparator<T> {
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

What are methods like .compareTo, .equals etc. called? Like, when I got some

```
obj1.compareTo(obj2);
```

how can I refer obj1, when I implement my own compareTo method?

Also the ComparableComparator.compare method should work for Rectangles and also other Generic types but I got no idea how to start this.

Comment: What do you mean "refer obj1"? I'm confused what exactly you're trying to do. Could you give an example of how the method would be used?

Comment: like the compareTo methods in RectangleComparatorArea. when i use r1.compareTo(r2), how can i adress r1 in my method. r2 is parameter based but for r1 i got no clue how to ask for it in if/else.

Comment: Are you sure you are not mixing up ```Comparator<...>``` and ```Comparable<...>``` with your nested classes? It seems a lot more sensible that they would implement the first.

Answer (score 0):

1. `this` . That's the reference to the object whose `compareTo` get called.
2. See how jdk's implementation works: [java.util.Comparators$NaturalOrderComparator](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/43cb25339b55/src/share/classes/java/util/Comparators.java#l47) (this is implementation detail and is hidden, tough)

Comment: I tried using this on my first go but I got an < or > is undefined for the argument types or other error's. I will check out the link ty.